dial tcp 192.168.48.2:3306: connect: connection refused
My connection to the DB keeps getting refused i tried to make sure all the ports were correct and parameters were matched up but i still keep getting this error
this is my docker compose file


services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    platform: linux/amd64
    container_name: mysql_container
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: user_password
    expose:
      - "3306"
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

  playgobackend:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./cmd/main/Dockerfile
    container_name: playgobackend
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_PORT: 3306
      DB_USER: user
      DB_PASSWORD: user_password
      DB_NAME: dbname

volumes:
  mysql-data:
networks:
  default:



this is the code I have to connect the go api to the database


var (
    db *gorm.DB
)

func Connect() {
    dsn := "user:user_password@tcp(db:3306)/dbname?charset=utf8mb4&parseTime=True&loc=Local"
    d, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    db = d
}



I tried changing the porst and tried using to root user instead but still giving me the same error.

Where does your code run?

Connection refused means that either mysql is not running, or not running on the specified host / port, or something is actively blocking the connection. Nothing to do with your mysql user name. You would get access denied if there was a problem with your mysql user name.

The mysql docker container states that it is running and I verified the ports but still receiving the same issues

Try to connect via container name as host name instead of service name or use the container's IP address. This is unlikely something we can resolve from here.


All code is available at https://github.com/mwmahlberg/go-gorm-78643564

Most likely, you have a race condition: Your application tries to connect to the database before it is ready. Using your code (mostly), I was able to reproduce the problem.
There are three main things you can do:

Use docker compose facilities to ensure the database is up and running before your application container is started.
Add a retry logic to your application
Use a rather nifty tool called dockerize to ensure the database is available before your application is started.

Using docker compose
Advantages:

No additional software required
simple to implement

Disadvantages:

Sometimes Fuzzy
Depends on the orchestration, namely docker compose

What you do here is twofold: You add a health check to the dependency and modify your depends_on statement to explicitly expect the dependency to be healthy (abbreviated for readability):
service:
  db:
    healtcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      start_interval: 10s
      start_period: 40s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10
  playgobackend:
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy

Now, docker-compose will only start the playgobackend container after the first successful startup check, which will be executed every 10s in the first 40s after the container was started.
Problem is: If you want to migrate to Kubernetes or even just running your application on a cli, you kind of have the same problem again. From my point of view, it is s stop-gap measure to get things running for a proof of concept, for example. For production use, one of the other solutions should be used.
Adding a retry logic to your application.
Advantages:

Works in every and any environment

Disadvantages:

Since the application appears to be running, some thought needs to be put into this solution from an operations point of view
Code ultimately dedicated to operations within your application violates the principle of separation of concerns.

The naive method would be something like this
for {
    db, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err == nil {
      break
    }
}

The obvious problem here is that the application will always appear to run while may or may not be stuck in a loop. A better way would be to try to establish the connection a couple of times and ultimately fail if none of the connection attempts was successful. While "a little copying is better than a little dependency" I like to use avast/retry-go for this purpose: It is simple to use, mature and has all the bells and whistles needed if you need them without making it complicated to use them (blocks and functions reordered for readability):
package main

import (
    "context"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
    "time"

    "github.com/avast/retry-go/v4"
    "gorm.io/driver/mysql"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    log.Println("starting up")

    dsn := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s:%s)/%s?%s", dbuser, dbpass, dbhost, dbport, dbname, dbparams)

    db, dbConnError := retry.DoWithData(
        // This function will be called until it returns nil or the number of attempts is reached
        // Note that it returns a *gorm.DB and an error, so we basically can use it easily
        // as a drop in replacement for gorm.Open.
        func() (*gorm.DB, error) {
            return gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
        },
        // Try 5 times with a 5 second delay between each attempt and only return the last error.
        // See https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/avast/retry-go/v4#Options for more options.
        retry.Attempts(5),
        retry.LastErrorOnly(true),
        retry.Delay(5*time.Second),
        retry.OnRetry(func(n uint, err error) {
            log.Printf("connection attempt %d failed: %s", n, err)
        }))

    if dbConnError != nil {
        panic(fmt.Errorf("failed to connect to database: %w", dbConnError))
    }

    log.Println("Migrating user table")
    if err := db.AutoMigrate(&User{}); err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Errorf("failed to migrate: %w", err))
    }

    log.Println("waiting for signal")
    ctx, cancel := signal.NotifyContext(context.Background(), syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
    defer cancel()
    <-ctx.Done()
    log.Println("shutting down")
}

// User is a dummy model for testing
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string
}

var (
    dbuser   string
    dbpass   string
    dbhost   string
    dbport   string
    dbname   string
    dbparams string
)

func init() {
    flag.StringVar(&dbuser, "dbuser", "user", "database user")
    flag.StringVar(&dbpass, "dbpass", "user_password", "database password")
    flag.StringVar(&dbhost, "dbhost", "db", "database host")
    flag.StringVar(&dbport, "dbport", "3306", "database port")
    flag.StringVar(&dbname, "dbname", "dbname", "database name")
    flag.StringVar(&dbparams, "dbparams", "charset=utf8mb4&parseTime=True&loc=Local", "additional database params")
}

Use dockerize
Advantages:

No changes to the actual code
dockerize can solve a whole slew of other problems arising from containerization of software.

Disadvantages:

Does not solve the problem when the application is running outside a container.
Container needs to be adapted.

Our use case is rather simple to implement: you put dockerize into your container, and have it call your application as soon as the mysql server is available:
CMD /usr/local/bin/dockerize -timeout 20s -wait tcp://${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT} /path/to/your/app

A more complete example:
FROM golang:1.22.4-alpine3.19 AS builder
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN go build -o main .

FROM alpine:3.19
ENV DOCKERIZE_VERSION v0.7.0

RUN apk update --no-cache \
  && apk add --no-cache wget openssl \
  && wget -O - https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize/releases/download/$DOCKERIZE_VERSION/dockerize-linux-amd64-$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz | tar xzf - -C /usr/local/bin
COPY --from=builder /app/main /usr/local/bin/migrate-users
CMD /usr/local/bin/dockerize -timeout 20s -wait tcp://${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT} /usr/local/bin/migrate-users

Conclusion
Now, the question arises "Which solution should I use?" and the answer as almost always is: "It depends."
If you can live with a little additional dependency and a few lines of additional code, I'd use retry-go. It is the most robust solution. However, if you are sure that your application will always run in a containerized environment and dockerize solves some additional problems for you, that might be the way to go. If you are just throwing together a PoC, though, both of those solutions might be a bit too much, and using docker compose to orchestrate the startup may well be sufficient.
hth.

Thanks this worked great. I thought having the depend_on property would be enough but I guess not.

@Whoisshaggy As documented.;) It only controls the startup order of the containers and cannot check whether the service provided in the container is ready.

The code example was extremely helpful. I was able to debug a different issue, that tcp(localhost:3306) kept failing with connect: refused connection. Apparently for services in docker, we should use tcp(db:3306) where db is the name of the database service.
